# C websocket disconnected

Tags: c, websocket

I've a problem with websocket. I have a particular need, so, sniffer continuous serial port (rs485) and send any data to the clients.
I've found many help in internet and my written program work correctly.
I have one last problem that I can not fix. Often the server for no reason  close the connection whith all clients and exit from c program.
I had to create a virtual buffer to ensure that there are data for all threads, because once you read the buffer of the serial it is emptied.
Websocket server is in C, websocket clients is in php/js.
I'm sorry for my orrible english.
This is my client:

```
var server_connection;
var rs485_connection;
var ping_serverconnection;
var ping_rs485connection
var sockethide=true;

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { socketConnection_close(); });

function socketConnection_open() {
    server_socketConnect();
    rs485_socketConnect();
}
function server_socketConnect() {
    server_connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.2.8:5000');
    server_connection.onopen = function () { serverOpened(); console.log('SERVER Connected!');};
    server_connection.onerror = function (error) { console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error); };
    server_connection.onmessage = function(e) { serverReceive(e.data); };
    server_connection.onclose = function(e) { serverClosed(); console.log('SERVER Disconnected!'); };
    ping_serverconnection=setInterval(function() {server_connection.send("ping");},5000);
}
function rs485_socketConnect() {
    rs485_connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.2.8:5001',"DomoProtocol");
    rs485_connection.onopen = function () { rs485Opened(); console.log('RS485 Connected!'); /*server_socketConnect()*/;};
    rs485_connection.onerror = function (error) { console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error); };
    rs485_connection.onmessage = function(e) { rs485Receive(e.data); };
    rs485_connection.onclose = function(e) { rs485Closed(); console.log('RS485 Disconnected!'); };
    //ping_rs485connection=setInterval(function() {rs485_connection.send("ping");},10000);
}
function socketConnection_close() {
    //clearInterval(ping_serverconnection);
    clearInterval(ping_rs485connection);
    //server_connection.send("exit");
    rs485_connection.send("exit");
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++);
    rs485_connection.close(); rs485_connection='';
    server_connection.close(); server_connection='';
}
function serverOpened() {
    document.getElementById("serverlightid").src=urlbase+"/images/icons/green.png";
}
function rs485Opened() {
    document.getElementById("rs485lightid").src=urlbase+"/images/icons/green.png";
}
function serverClosed() {
    server_connection.close(); server_connection='';
    document.getElementById("serverlightid").src=urlbase+"/images/icons/red.png";
    //server_socketConnect();
}
function rs485Closed() {
    rs485_connection.close(); rs485_connection='';    
    document.getElementById("rs485lightid").src=urlbase+"/images/icons/red.png";
}
function socketexpand() {
    if (sockethide) {
        document.getElementById("socketDivId").style.width="500px";
        document.getElementById("socketDivId").style.height="400px";
        document.getElementById("socketexpandid").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("sockethideid").style.display="inline";
        sockethide=false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("socketDivId").style.width="80px";
        document.getElementById("socketDivId").style.height="25px";
        document.getElementById("socketexpandid").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("sockethideid").style.display="none";
        sockethide=true;
    }
}

// *******************************************************************************************************
function serverReceive(msg) { alert("Dato Ricevuto server:"+msg); }

function server_connection_send(msg) {
    server_connection.send(msg);
    var node = document.createElement("span");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(msg+" ");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("serversocketdivid").appendChild(node);
}

function rs485Receive(msg) {
    //var content=document.getElementById("rs485socketdivid");
    var node = document.createElement("span");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(msg+" ");         
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("rs485socketdivid").appendChild(node);     
    //alert("Dato Ricevuto 485:"+msg);
}
function rs485_connection_send(msg) {
    rs485_connection.send(msg);
    var node = document.createElement("span");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(msg+" ");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("serversocketdivid").appendChild(node);
}
```

And this is my server in c:

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>    
//for threading , link with lpthread
#include<pthread.h> 
//for SHA1 + BASE64
#include <openssl/sha.h>
const char *BASE64_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
//for serial
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 1000
#define DELAYTOSEND 1000000
#define MAX_CONNECTION 10
void *connection_handler(void *);
void *connection_handler_master(void *);
int serialBuffer[MAX_BUFFER];
long arg;


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c , *new_sock, i;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000], query[200]="";
    char *message, *token, *key;

    unsigned char obuf[20];
    unsigned char b64[100];

    //thread MASTER
    for(i=0;i<(MAX_BUFFER+1);i++) serialBuffer[i]=-1;
    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    new_sock = malloc(1);
    *new_sock = new_socket;
     if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler_master , (void*) new_sock) < 0) {
            perror("Non posso creare il Thread MASTER");
            return 1;
        }
    puts("Thread MASTER creato");

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)     {
        printf("Impossibile creare un socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;            //IPv4
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
    server.sin_port = htons( 5001 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        puts("bind fallito");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind OK");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , MAX_CONNECTION);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("In attesa di connessione...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) ) {
        puts("Connessione accetata");
        recv(new_socket, client_message , 2000 , 0);
        token=strtok(client_message,"\r\n");
        //DEBUG while(token) { printf( "--------->:  %s\n", token ); token=strtok(NULL,"\r\n"); } printf("----------------------------------------\r\n");

        while(token != NULL) {
            if(!strncmp(token,"Sec-WebSocket-Key:",18)) break; //printf( "%s\n", token );
            token=strtok(NULL,"\r\n");
        }
        key=strtok(token," ");
        key=strtok(NULL," ");
        strcat(key,"258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
        SHA1(key,strlen(key),obuf);
        base64_encode(obuf,20,b64,100);

        printf( "KEY:  %s\n", key );
        printf( "B64:  %s\n", b64 );

        strcat(query,"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n");
        strcat(query,"Upgrade: Websocket\r\n");
        strcat(query,"Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
        strcat(query,"Sec-Websocket-Protocol:DomoProtocol\r\n");
        strcat(query,"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ");
        strcat(query,b64);
        strcat(query,"\r\n\r\n");

        //DEBUG puts(token);        
        printf( "%s\n", query );
        write(new_socket , query , strlen(query));
        query[0]='\0';

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0) {
            perror("Non posso creare il thread");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Thread creato, Handler assegnato");
        printf("new_sock:%i\r\n",new_sock);
    }

    if (new_socket<0) {
        perror("Connessione rifiutata");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("uscita1");
    return 0;
}
/**
 * encode three bytes using base64 (RFC 3548)
 */
void _base64_encode_triple(unsigned char triple[3], char result[4])  {
    int tripleValue, i;
    tripleValue = triple[0];
    tripleValue *= 256;
    tripleValue += triple[1];
    tripleValue *= 256;
    tripleValue += triple[2];
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) { result[3-i] = BASE64_CHARS[tripleValue%64]; tripleValue /= 64; }
}
/**
 * encode an array of bytes using Base64 (RFC 3548)
 * return 1 on success, 0 otherwise
 */  
int base64_encode(unsigned char *source, size_t sourcelen, char *target, size_t targetlen) {
    if ((sourcelen+2)/3*4 > targetlen-1) return 0;

    /* encode all full triples */
    while (sourcelen >= 3) {
        _base64_encode_triple(source, target);
        sourcelen -= 3;
        source += 3;
        target += 4;
    }

    if (sourcelen > 0) {
        unsigned char temp[3];
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
        memcpy(temp, source, sourcelen);
        _base64_encode_triple(temp, target);
        target[3] = '=';
        if (sourcelen == 1) target[2] = '=';
        target += 4;
    }

    target[0] = 0;
    return 1;
} 
/**
 * determine the value of a base64 encoding character
 * return the value in case of success (0-63), -1 on failure
 */  
int _base64_char_value(char base64char) {
    if (base64char >= 'A' && base64char <= 'Z')  return base64char-'A';
    if (base64char >= 'a' && base64char <= 'z')  return base64char-'a'+26;
    if (base64char >= '0' && base64char <= '9')  return base64char-'0'+2*26;
    if (base64char == '+')  return 2*26+10;
    if (base64char == '/')  return 2*26+11;
    return -1;
} 
/**
 * decode a 4 char base64 encoded byte triple
 * return lenth of the result (1, 2 or 3), 0 on failure
 */  
int _base64_decode_triple(char quadruple[4], unsigned char *result) {
    int i, triple_value, bytes_to_decode = 3, only_equals_yet = 1;
    int char_value[4];

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) char_value[i] = _base64_char_value(quadruple[i]);

    for (i=3; i>=0; i--) {
        if (char_value[i]<0) {
            if (only_equals_yet && quadruple[i]=='=') {
                char_value[i]=0;
                bytes_to_decode--;
                continue;
            }
        return 0;
        }
        only_equals_yet = 0;
    }

    if (bytes_to_decode < 0) bytes_to_decode = 0;

    triple_value = char_value[0];   triple_value *= 64;
    triple_value += char_value[1];  triple_value *= 64;
    triple_value += char_value[2];  triple_value *= 64;
    triple_value += char_value[3];

    for (i=bytes_to_decode; i<3; i++) triple_value /= 256;
    for (i=bytes_to_decode-1; i>=0; i--) { result[i] = triple_value%256; triple_value /= 256; }

    return bytes_to_decode;
} 
/**
 * decode base64 encoded data
 * return length of converted data on success, -1 otherwise
 */  
size_t base64_decode(char *source, unsigned char *target, size_t targetlen) {
    char *src, *tmpptr;
    char quadruple[4], tmpresult[3];
    int i, tmplen = 3;
    size_t converted = 0;

    src = (char *)malloc(strlen(source)+5);
    if (src == NULL) return -1;
    strcpy(src, source);
    strcat(src, "====");
    tmpptr = src;

    while (tmplen == 3) {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
             while (*tmpptr != '=' && _base64_char_value(*tmpptr)<0) tmpptr++;
             quadruple[i] = *(tmpptr++);
        }
        tmplen = _base64_decode_triple(quadruple, tmpresult);
        if (targetlen < tmplen) { free(src); return -1; }
        memcpy(target, tmpresult, tmplen);
        target += tmplen;
        targetlen -= tmplen;
        converted += tmplen;
    }
    free(src);
    return converted;
}
/*
 * Serial Open
 */
int serialOpen (char *device, int baud) {
    struct termios options ;
    speed_t myBaud ;
    int     status, fd ;

    if ((fd = open (device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) return -1 ;

    fcntl (fd, F_SETFL, O_RDWR) ;
    tcgetattr (fd, &options) ;
    cfmakeraw   (&options) ;
    cfsetispeed (&options, B115200) ;
    cfsetospeed (&options, B115200) ;
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD) ;
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB ;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB ;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE ;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8 ;
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG) ;
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST ;
    options.c_cc [VMIN]  =   0 ;
    options.c_cc [VTIME] = 100 ;    // Ten seconds (100 deciseconds)

    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW | TCSAFLUSH, &options) ;
    ioctl (fd, TIOCMGET, &status);
    status |= TIOCM_DTR ;
    status |= TIOCM_RTS ;
    ioctl (fd, TIOCMSET, &status);
    usleep (10000) ;    // 10mS
    return fd ;
}
/*
 * DECODE / ENCODE STRING TO BINARY
 * */
char * decode( char *frame) {
    static char text[2000];
    int ofs=0, len=0, i=0, a=0;
    len = (int)(frame[1]) & 127;

    if (len == 126) { ofs = 8; }
        else if (len == 127) { ofs = 14; }
        else { ofs = 6; }
    text[0] = '\0';
    for (i = ofs; i < strlen(frame); i++) { text[a] = frame[i] ^ frame[ofs - 4 + (i - ofs) % 4]; a++; }
    text[a] = '\0';
    return text;
}
char * encode( char *frame) {
    int indexStartRawData=-1, i=0;
    long long int len=0;
    static char  bytesFormatted[2000];
    for(i=0;i<2000;i++) bytesFormatted[i]='\0';
    len = strlen(frame);
    bytesFormatted[0]= 129;
    if (len <= 125) {
        bytesFormatted[1] = len;
        indexStartRawData = 2;
    } else if (len >= 126 && len <= 65535) {
        bytesFormatted[1] = 126;
        bytesFormatted[2] = ( len >> 8 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[3] = ( len ) && 255;
        indexStartRawData = 4;
    } else {
        bytesFormatted[1] = 127;
        bytesFormatted[2] = ( len >> 56 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[3] = ( len >> 48 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[4] = ( len >> 40 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[5] = ( len >> 32 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[6] = ( len >> 24 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[7] = ( len >> 16 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[8] = ( len >>  8 ) && 255;
        bytesFormatted[9] = ( len ) && 255;
        indexStartRawData = 10;
    }
    strcat( bytesFormatted,frame);
    bytesFormatted[indexStartRawData+len] ='\0';
    return bytesFormatted;
}
char * asciiencode( int asciichar)  {
    int indexStartRawData=-1, i=0, len=0;
    static char bytesFormatted[10];
    static char asciiFormatted[10];
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++) bytesFormatted[i]='\0';

    sprintf(asciiFormatted,"%i\0",asciichar);
    len = strlen(asciiFormatted);
    bytesFormatted[0]= 129;
    bytesFormatted[1] = len;
    indexStartRawData = 2;

    strcat( bytesFormatted,asciiFormatted);
    bytesFormatted[indexStartRawData+len] =0;
    bytesFormatted[indexStartRawData+len+1] =0;
    bytesFormatted[indexStartRawData+len+2] ='\0';
    //bytesFormatted[indexStartRawData+len] ='\r';
    //bytesFormatted[indexStartRawData+len+1] ='\n';

    return bytesFormatted;
}

/*
 * Thread MASTER to popolate virtual array
 * */
void *connection_handler_master (void *socket_desc) {
     //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *server_message , client_message[2000];
    int i=0;

    //Send some messages to the client
    server_message = "Creazione MASTER avvenuta. ";
    printf("%s\r\n",server_message);
    server_message = "In attesa di dati sul bus RS485.";
    printf("%s\r\n",server_message);
    int handle;
    uint8_t x ;
    handle = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200) ;
    //for(i=0;i<2001;i++) printf("%i: %i\r\n ",i,serialBuffer[i]);

    while(1) {
        while(!read (handle, &x, 1));
        if(x>-1) {
            serialBuffer[i]=x;
            //DEBUG printf("%i-%i\r\n",i,serialBuffer[i]);
            if(i==MAX_BUFFER) { serialBuffer[0]=-1; i=0; }
            else { serialBuffer[i+1]=-1; i++; }
        }
        x=-1;
    }

}
/*
 * Thread clients
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc) {
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc, read_size, i=0, a=0;
    char *server_message , client_message[2000], *c;


    //Send some messages to the client
    server_message = "Connessione avvenuta. ";
    write(sock , encode(server_message) , strlen(encode(server_message)));

    server_message = "In attesa di dati sul buffer.";
    write(sock , encode(server_message) , strlen(encode(server_message)));
    //DEBUG printf("sock:%i\r\n",sock);
    while(serialBuffer[i]!=-1) i++;

    while(1) {
        if(serialBuffer[i]!=-1) {
            //DEBUG printf("Serialdata%i: %i\r\n",i,serialBuffer[i]);
            server_message=asciiencode(serialBuffer[i]);
            write(sock , server_message , strlen(server_message));

            //printf("Serialdata--------------->%i: %s\r\n",i,server_message);

            if(i==MAX_BUFFER) i=0;
            else i++;
            for(a=0;a<DELAYTOSEND;a++) { }
        }

    }

    // This code is not used
    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 ) {
        //Received message from client
        //printf( "%s\n", decode(client_message) );

        //send message to client            
        //server_message="provina";
        //write(sock , encode(server_message) , strlen(encode(server_message)));
        printf( "%s\n",decode(client_message));
        //read (handle, &x, 1);
        //sprintf(c,"%i",x);
        //write (sock, encode(c),strlen(encode(c) ) );
        printf("serialBUffer: %s\r\n",serialBuffer);

    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        puts("uscita2");
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    puts("uscita3");
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading quickly, there's a suspicious `new_sock = malloc(1);` whereas the copied object is int. Moreover, malloc could fail. But that's probably not your problem, and malloc could provide a large enough chunk for the int eitherway.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think malloc is not the problem because all clients can connect with server. Connection stay up several hours without problem if serial dont receive data. 
When serial transmit data, data are sent to the clients, but at some point when serial trasmit data some are transmitted but not all because connection  is close by the server...

Comment: It might not be THE problem, but it is A problem.

Comment: Why not use a websocket server library...? This way you will have code that was reviewed and you can concentrate on the stuff that you want to implement.